# Is it possible to add a favicon to sefl-hosted web api service?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, favicon, microservices, self-host-webapi

I have many services that I'm moving from ordinary Web API to Owin/Katana as self-hosted web api services. Because we were somehow using Microservices, we have many small services that would run and all of them had the same favicon.ico that showed our branding across our services to developers. Is it possible to add a favicon to self-hosted web api? How?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a `GET` request to `/favicon.ico` just needs to return your favicon file.

I haven't set up Katana routing before, but you could try the `Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles` package, and you can set up [something like this](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx).